# Embedding HTML5 Widgets in DataTables in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm currently following https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/410 in order to try to figure out how to embed HTML5 widgets in DataTables. The code that was provided works completely fine when I was running it in a standalone script, but I need to have the DataTable with the widget embedded within my Shiny app.

```
 output$dt <- renderDT({
      data <- ...some data here
      data_with_json <- data %>% mutate(json = NA)

      for (row in 1:nrow(data_with_json)) {
        json <- data_with_json[[2]][row]
        data_with_json[[3]][row] = as.character.htmlwidget(jsonedit(json))
      }

      data_with_json <- data_with_json %>% select(-json)

      dt <- data_with_json %>%
        datatable(
          options,
          selection = "none",
          rownames = FALSE,
          width = "100%",
          height = "100%",
          colnames = c("1", "2"),
          style = "bootstrap",
          class = "table-striped table-hover",
          escape = FALSE
        ) %>%
        addWidget('jsonedit', 'listviewer')
      return(dt)
    })
```

The helper functions referenced from the issue are

```
# Helper functions (to be added to HTMLWidgets) ----
as.character.htmlwidget <- function(x){
  as.character(htmlwidgets:::toHTML(x))
}

staticRenderJS <- htmlwidgets::JS('function(){
    HTMLWidgets.staticRender()                                    
}')


#' Add a widget to a htmlwidget
addWidget <- function(x, widget, package = widget, ...){
  UseMethod('addWidget')
}

#' The default method simply attaches the widget dependencies and
#' rerenders all widgets on the page. The code can be cleaned up
#' to only render the widget in question
addWidget.default <- function(x, widget, package = widget){
  x %>% tagList(
    htmlwidgets::getDependency(widget, package),
    onStaticRenderComplete(
      "HTMLWidgets.staticRender()"
    )
  ) %>%
    browsable
  return(x) <--- tried explicit return here
}


#' DT can add its own S3 method for addWidget that allows a callback code to 
#' be run right after the table is rendered. We take advantage of that here
addWidget.DT <- function(x, widget, package = widget, ...){
  x$x$options$fnDrawCallback = staticRenderJS
  x %>% tagList(deps) %>% browsable
  return(x) <-- tried explicitly returning here
}
```

So it seems that in the `addWidget`, it doesn't return a dataframe or matrix as I get the following error.

```
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)
  105: stop
  104: <Anonymous>
  102: processWidget
  101: widgetFunc
  100: func
   87: origRenderFunc
   86: renderFunc
   82: origRenderFunc
   81: output$dt
    1: runApp
```

If I have the helper functions explicitly return the passed in DT during the pipe, the widget never renders. Could anyone point to me what I might be missing? Is it the `browsable` function causing issues?

When I put the explicit returns of the datable in, the table will render but none of the widget features (https://github.com/timelyportfolio/listviewer) show up and that space is just blank.

Comment: for reference cross-posted here https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/410#issuecomment-628939073 with potentially multiple answers